# MOC3041 + T810-600B issue

Tags: triac

For some reason, the lamp is always on, even if the DC side is disconnected - no 3.3V.

Any ideas?

[image: Trica control]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change terminals A1 and A2 of the TRIAC. The output of the optocoupler must be placed between A2 and G. R15 now permanently turns on the TRIAC.

Comment: Thankyou to @csabahu. I had this exact same problem and was tearing my hair out until I found your answer. I mistakenly thought that the A1 and A2 pins were interchangeable. So great to have this forum to search.